# find the absolute maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y)=4x^2+9y^2-8x-12y+4$ ,problem is i think is with the method

Tags: calculus

I happen to check the graph on a 3d calculator and i found that the function's limits are $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, the $f(x,y)$ extends to infinities as $(x,y)$ tends to $\infty$ .
But the problem in my reference book solves using making the first derivative of function equal to zero with respect to $x$ and $y$  and reap the critical points from solving the derivative equalled to zero and checking if $rt-s^2$ is $>/<0$.

Please check the 3dgraph for your reference too

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square gives us

$f(x,y)=4(x-1)^2+9(y-\frac{2}{3})^2-4$

Clearly as $x$ and $y$ approach infinity the function will also approach infinity so there is no absolute maximum. Since the first two terms are squared, they will always be positive or $0$. To minimize the function we want them to be $0$ which occurs when $x=1$ and $y=\frac{2}{3}$, this gives the function a minimum value of $-4$.

Comment: exactly what i said, but in my book the author proceeds with the calculating critical point and yeilds a relative maxima point'